# Recommend me a quick setup local http/php/mysql server for development (WIndows)

Tags: local

I need a quick and dirty http server to use for local application development, that supports php and mysql. Xampp will not work for me (64 bit Win 7), so Im looking for something similar.

Comment: Yah, cant get it to work either. Apache just wont run.

Answer (score 3):

I've had good experience with [The Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com/) -- it's portable*, and it includes Apache, PHP, MySQL, and Perl in the box.  [Their installation manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Installation_on_Uniform_Server_(Windows)#Windows) also says testing has been successful on 64-bit WinXP Pro.

* It's portable in the put it on your USB-stick and use it on any Windows computer sense.  They also claim to not touch the Windows registry at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try Wamp server

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it includes MySQL, but check out the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). It *does* include PHP and a lot of other stuff. All Free.

Answer (score 0):

[pmwikiserv](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/Standalone) is a wiki that includes a free standalone single executable PHP/http server for windows/Unix

Answer (score 0):

- [Wamp Server](http://www.wampserver.com)
- [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout WebGUI (http://www.plainblack.com/) which comes with a quick install web server, mysql database, and content management system all in one. Works on Windows, Unix, Mac, BSD and Linux. Needs Perl. You can add on PHP and/or Python to make it do what you want. The system is entirely open source (you can pay for support). Under active development by a going commercial concern. Setup in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows XP Professional or a Windows Server installation, run it on [IIS](http://www.iis.net/).  I'm sure it's included on the higher end Vista distribution discs too.  You can check by inserted your disc, going to Add or Remove Programs and on the left menu, select Add Windows Features...something like that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Abyss Web Server 
http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws/

The setup is trivial. Also, it only takes a couple of minutes to enable cgi (they are recognized by extension).

Also, many frameworks such as django and groovy/grails come with their own simple server.