# How can I download and install correctly apache with PHP, MySQL, etc... for localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, localhost

Please I need help, I have a project, but i'm tired of making my code and uploading it to the server, I need a localhost to make it more faster and I was thinking of apache but I don't know how to download it correctly

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489300/recommend-me-a-quick-setup-local-http-php-mysql-server-for-development-windows/1489347#1489347. I use XAMPP, which the OP in the linked question says doesn't work on his machine, but I've never had any trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are going to install them one by one it will be a bit tricky (for beginners).
If you have never done it before I recommend Zend Server Community edition. The installer is pretty good it sets up everything for you.

http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/free-edition

But if you are an adventurous kind the minimum I would imagine you would need to install is

- Apache Httpd => http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi
- PHP => http://php.net/downloads.php
- MySQL => http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

As you haven't mentioned which OS you want to configure it on. But I think you will find a lot of tutorials for any platform for each.

Comment: You are magnificent, I think I will first try with the easiest one and then when I have better knowledge of this I would do the other one :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

man just download [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), a few click install.. and done.. since you sound like you have no idea of how to start... then this would be perfect.. just check it out for your self.

Comment: Thank you, if my other option doesn't work, I will keep you in mind